# Application crash

Tags: c#

My application uses twain dll for scanning documents. There are so many users using my application. But for few users my application hangs and getting the error that my application stopped working. The users reported this issue are using either windows vista or windows 7 version. The memory dump shows “System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException”. Please see below the stack trace taken from the memory dump.

STACK_TEXT:

77a6015d ntdll!RtlReportCriticalFailure+0x5b

77a60d68 ntdll!RtlpReportHeapFailure+0x21

77a60e56 ntdll!RtlpLogHeapFailure+0xa1

77a2b0c8 ntdll!RtlSizeHeap+0x69

778212e0 ole32!CRetailMalloc_GetSize+0x21

767f43d9 oleaut32!APP_DATA::FreeCachedMem+0x30

767f3e6c oleaut32!SysFreeString+0x6b

118b1647 VM31bTXP+0x1647

779ee1c4 ntdll!LdrpCallInitRoutine+0x14

779e8dea ntdll!LdrpUnloadDll+0x3d8

779ee8e2 ntdll!LdrUnloadDll+0x46

76aa0979 kernel32!FreeLibrary+0x15

597d6512 twain!CDataSrc::unload+0x22

597d66b9 twain!CDataSrc::SendMessageA+0x81

597d6c1e twain!CDataSrc::identityMsg+0x18

597d6d0d twain!CDataSrc::MessageNoAppCheck+0x47

597d6e14 twain!CDataSrc::IDataSrc+0xd0

597d58f6 twain!CDsm::registerDS+0x1b7

597d5ca3 twain!CDsm::registerDirDSs+0x163

597d5c87 twain!CDsm::registerDirDSs+0x147

597d5dc7 twain!CDsm::findAndRegisterDSs+0x85

597d5ed9 twain!CDsm::findClosestDefaultDS+0xcc

597d634d twain!CDsm::identityMsg+0x17e

597d6404 twain!CDsm::Message+0x91

597d8ec6 twain!DSM_Entry+0x102

0540605c unknown+0x0

119792d3 unknown+0x0

11979255 unknown+0x0

68991eab System_Windows_Forms_ni+0xa51eab

68991eab System_Windows_Forms_ni+0xa51eab

68120317 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x1e0317

68136d71 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x1f6d71

68136d1a System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x1f6d1a

68136d1a System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x1f6d1a

68136b74 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x1f6b74

68140207 System_Windows_Forms_ni+0x200207

Please advise when such exception happens

Comment: We're going to need a lot more information than that. Can you run the program from Visual Studio with debuggers attached? If not, does anything show up in the Event Log? You should get a complete exception report.

Comment: start debugger: F5 ... (when you don't know how to debug it, it most probably does not belong to stackoverflow ...)

Answer (score 1):

If you are having a debugger like VS2005 then why dont you step into the code so that you can identify where exactly the crash occured.

Please also tell what is the exception that you get.

If you dont have access to debugger then you can get DebugDiag or WinDbg software and catch the crash dump and analyse it with the help of a pdb.